# javascript, including variables from loop inside google functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So you have probably seen something similar alot, where someone has a problem with using the "i" variable in a functions inside a for loop. Now that can easily be fixed with:

```
(function(){
    return function() {
        //something
    }
})(i);
```

But, how do I do this in my scenario?

```
GMap.prototype.drawDirection = function (directionsRenderer, directionsService, headMarker, tailMarkers, callback) {
var request;
var array = [];
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tailMarkers.length; i++) {
    count = i;

    request = {
        origin: headMarker.getPosition(),
        destination: tailMarkers[i].getPosition(),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            console.log(i + " " + count);
            callback(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value, i, tailMarkers.length - 1);
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
        }
    });
    }
};
```

To be more accurate, it's about the directionsService object:

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        console.log(i + " " + count);
        callback(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value, i, tailMarkers.length - 1);
    } else {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Now, I don't want to use JFiddle since it would be alot to write, so I'm just going to link to my site where I'm trying this.

http://stud.aitel.hist.no/~andersfy/html5.proj/

If you look at the checkbox in the bottom right corner, where it says "vis min posisjon" you just need to click on that, and you'll see the problem.

The code is in the file galled GMap.js at line 134 to 142.
I hope I'm giving you enough information!

Comment: Just btw, this doesn't work: http://pastebin.com/Ni4H9w38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create functions inside of for loops for this very reason.

Your problem is in this closure, that shares the variable  *i*:

```
function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        console.log(i + " " + count);
        callback(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value, i, tailMarkers.length - 1);
    } else {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
}
```

I would rewrite that function to not depend on `i`, but if you need `i` then

```
/*before your for loop */
function createRouter(i){
    return function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            console.log(i + " " + count);
            callback(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value, i, tailMarkers.length - 1);
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
        }
    }
};

/* in your for loop */
directionsService.route(request, createRouter(i));
```